# Javascript returned object properties undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

These are some relevant HTML elements that I work with:

```
                <TD id=Cell.0.0>
                   <DIV></DIV>
                   <IMG id=_Q0_C0_mrSingleImg src="radio.gif">
                   <INPUT type="checkbox" name=_QGender_C class=mrSingle id=_Q0_C0> 
                   <LABEL for=_Q0_C0>
                      <SPAN class=mrSingleText >
                        some text
                      </SPAN>
                   </LABEL>
                </TD>
```

In my main JS file, I first assign this onClick method to the img element:

```
function onImageClickSingle(event) {

    // catch clicked img element
    event = event || window.event;
    var img = event.target || event.srcElement;  // IE fix
    if (img.nodeType == 3) img = img.parentNode; // firefix bug fix

    var inputSibling = getNextSibling(img);

    // some more code that involves working with inputSibling attributes...
}
```

As you can see, in the above function I call "getNextSibling" to get the image sibling, that is the input element.
Since the code must support older version of IE, I added this "getNextSibling" function to my fix.js file, as was recommended on another stack overflow thread:

```
// IE 8 and less do not support nextSibling or previousSibling javascript properties 
function getNextSibling(element) {
    var sibling = $('#' + element.id + '').next();
    return sibling;
}
```

The problem I encounter is that when debugging code, I can see that inputSibling variable does contain the requested input sibling element that "getNextSibling" returns (id, checked, class name etc, are all assigned a value), but when I try to work with either of the returned object's attributs, they are all undefined.

Anyone has an idea of why this might happen?

Comment: You'll have to show the part where the values are undefined. There's nothing in the code you've shown that would explain it.

Comment: Hi Juhana, thank you for the reply. In the getNextSibling function the attributes are already undefined.

Comment: Probably something is messed up with the dynamic selector. Since you already have a reference to the element you don't have to search for it again. Just use `$(element).next();`.

Comment: You use a jQuery function, that will return a jQuery Object. To get a regular DOM Object from a jQuery Object use the `[0]` operator. Or do the same without jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function returns jQuery object

```
function getNextSibling(element) {
    var sibling = $('#' + element.id + '').next();
    return sibling;
}
```

so you will be able to access the attributes using attr()

```
inputSibling.attr('id')
```

or if you want to continue with JS access style you need to

```
inputSibling.get(0).id
```

Comment: Thank you very much volkinc, that was exactly the error I wasn't aware of